# Accessing file system outside the chroot jail

Tags: linux

We are working on creating a user on a CentOS system who would work in a chrooted environment only. While this works fine in general, we also want this user to be able to access some configuration files which we keep in /etc and /opt. Read only access is necessary as we don't want the user to be able to change these files.
The questions is how to provide this read only access.

Comment: whats ur question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I found the answer myself. I used a utility called [bindfs](http://bindfs.org) and remounted my host directories inside of chroot in read only mode as needed.

Answer (score 1):

for directories, i would recommend mounting the directories as readonly

```
for DIR in $DIRECTORIES ; do
    mount --bind $DIR "$CHROOT_DIR$DIR" -o ro
done
```

For files, I guess you can just copy them into the chrooted environment each time. (Unless you need changes to them to be available immediately to the user, it should work.

```
for FILE in $FILES ; do
    cp $FILE "$CHROOT_DIR$FILE"
done
```

Comment: I tried this already but if a directory or file system is already mounted read write, it cannot be mounted again using mount with different options (i.e ro in this case).